# Trying to recover an SD card

Tags: xubuntu, data-recovery, sd-card

This is an SD card that doesn't show up when I insert it into my Ubuntu (Actually Xubuntu 16.04 LTS). The problem is specific to this SD card, I can insert another card which is fine. Both are micro cards that slot into an adapter before they can fit into the SD card holder on my machine, so I use the same adapter for both micro cards. One works and one doesn't. I figure the problem is the card rather than the OS, the reader or the adapter.
When I push the bad card in and

```
dmesg | tail -20
```

I get:

```
[104901.790536] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[104902.093191] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[104904.469067] mmc0: card never left busy state
```

I have looked at tools like testdisk and they all assume the device is detected. For example ls /dev/mmc* gives me no such file or directory.
Are there any other options of have I lost the data on my card forever?

Comment: Have you tried it in another computer or other device? Perhaps it is toast.

Comment: @jpezz yes, I tried it in an Android Tablet. Not recognised there either. It used to work fine on that and on my laptop.

Comment: I have had an SAD card die on me before, what happened is pretty similar to what is happening for you. My guess is that it's not recoverable, but it's worth trying to get it to work again.

Comment: SD card, not SAD card, although it was pretty sad. I seem to be in an ongoing war with Autocorrect.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/849699/error-whilst-initializing-sd-card-on-linux